# R's switch statement is not a special form, is it therefore slow?

Tags: r, performance, switch-statement

In most languages with `switch` statements, `switch` is a special form designed such that the possibilities are evaluated lazily and the compiler knows how to optimise the selection of statements based on the given input. R, mostly already being lazy, does not need some of this. However, R's `switch` statement is still a function call, rather than any sort of special form. Does this mean that R's `switch` statement is slower than it would be if it were a special form? Or does R's interpreter know to optimise it as if it were a special form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at internal code of `switch` in file [src/main/builtin.c](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/builtin.c), you can read in lines 1009-1025 :

> This is a SPECIALSXP, so arguments need to be evaluated as needed.

`SPECIALSXP` [means](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html) :

```
no  SEXPTYPE    Description
7   SPECIALSXP  special functions
```

So `switch` is actually a [special function](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-lang.html#Builtin-objects-and-special-forms) which passes unevaluated arguments to the internal function.

Further reading the source code from line 1030 to line 1104 shows that as explained in `?switch`, the function either handles `character` or `number` in a simple and not fully optimized way.

This probably explains why `switch` isn't particularly fast in situations which would for example require a binary search.

Comment: No knock on your answer that I just upvoted, but this tautology made me smile : "arguments need to be evaluated as needed."

Comment: Glad to know that the lazinesss is covered, but what about classic switch optimizations like using a binary search when you're switching on an integer against a huge number of cases?

Comment: `switch` source code are the 70+ lines  from 1030 to 1104 in the link above. I don't see there much optimization, which probably explains the slowness in the situations you describe.

Comment: @Waldi Stick something like that in the answer and it's safe to say that you've probably got the bounty.